Sound quality issue when saving in vue-audio-recorder-and-player
I am encountering an issue with the vue-audio-recorder-and-player package. When I save the sound, the audio becomes very thick and unreal. What steps should I take to solve this problem?
By changing the sample-rate, the sound still does not work
Initialize the vue-audio-recorder-and-player package.
Record a sound.
Save the sound.
Observe that the saved sound becomes very thick and unreal.
